# How can I plot lists that contain a date and integer on the same graph(correlation)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot these lists on a graph. The first element being the x points and the second being the y points. Basically, every list is one point.
So one point will be ((2009,4,2,22,50,60),0) and so on. They all should be plotted on the same graph and connected with a line. The data i have is very big and are stored in a text file whihc is 2GB. Here is a sample of how my data looks like.

```
[datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 2, 22, 50, 6), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 2, 23, 47, 41), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 2, 23, 54, 37), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 15, 21, 58, 14), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 29, 13, 12, 23), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 5, 18, 21, 13), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 11, 21, 8), 0]
```

My code is: (note: the "word" variable is the list for the text file, ie: my data)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sentmod as s
with open('newdata.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    tweet=re.sub(r'T\t',"",line)
    t=re.sub(r'W\t',"\/\/",tweet)
    data=t.split("\/\/")
    sentiment_value= s.sentiment(data[1])
    data.append(sentiment_value)

    words = [w.replace('pos', '1') for w in data]
    word=[w.replace('neg','0')for w in words]
    del word[1]
    word[1]=int(word[1])

    word[0]=datetime.strptime(word[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ')
    print(word)
```

I tried adding this

```
    values= (word)
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.plot_date([value[0] for value in values], [value[1] for value in values], "-o")
    plt.show()
```

but i get the following error:

```
   TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

[Outcome when adding the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJKWY.png)

Comment: Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get the problem here, why not simply use the [plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot_date#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date) function ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

values = [
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 2, 22, 50, 6), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 2, 23, 47, 41), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 2, 23, 54, 37), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 15, 21, 58, 14), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 29, 13, 12, 23), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 5, 18, 21, 13), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 11, 21, 8), 0]
    ]

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot_date([value[0] for value in values], [value[1] for value in values], "-o")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I would use plot date, but I am having a problem defining the values. I have changed my question to clarify something I haven't. my data, which are lists, are stored in a text file. What you did was define the values as the lists I showed. But what I forgot to mention is that the ones I showed is a sample of a  2GB file with such lists. Is there a way I can define values by using my variable word which represents my data coming from the file?

Comment: This works when i did th method you used, but i cant do it for the 2 BG file

Comment: Maybe you should look at an other solution, such as pandas for example.